# How to map a file handle to the file it is accessing

Tags: tcl

I am trying to map a file handle like `file6` 
(the result of a previous `set fh [open somefile.txt w]`) to the file it was accessing.

So I'd like a mapping between file6 --> somefile.txt

I tried `file channels`, but this only lists the channel names - not the actual file name.

Answer (score 1):

As you've noticed, Tcl doesn't keep this information for you, but you can easily keep track of it for yourself by doing something like this:

```
set fh [open somefile.txt w]
set filenames($fh) somefile.txt
```

Then when you want to know the associated file name, you can

```
puts $filenames($fh)
```

You can automate this by e.g.:

```
proc myOpen {name args} {
    global filenames
    set fh [open $name {*}$args]
    set filenames($fh) $name
    return $fh
}
```

This is of course a quick-and-dirty semi-solution that leaves some important things open, like for instance how the association needs to be similarly removed if the channel is closed. It is possible, but a bit complicated, to create a more comprehensive solution.

Documentation:
[global](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/global.htm),
[open](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/open.htm),
[proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[return](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/return.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: You could use a pushed transform to remove the mapping automatically on close, but that's a little messy.

Comment: @DonalFellows Was it ever considered to provide such a thingie as a `chan configure -filename` read-only option? Anything being a barrier to this other than doing and TIP'ing it?

Comment: @mrcalvin I simply don't think anyone's ever got round to it before; I think it would be a reasonable addition (at least if the interpreter asking for the information is the caller of `open`, or not safe).